# Allure-results directory is created but Allure reports are not generated (Allure with Gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, allure

I've browsed through the forum but was unable to find the solution for my problem. I am running my tests on IntelliJ with Gradle. The intended directory "build/allure-results" is created, as expected, but it stays empty. Here's what build.gradle file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "io.qameta.allure"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    agent
}

compileTestGroovy {
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += "-Xmx256m"
}


dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.13' //needed for spock reports
    testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15' //groovy
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4") { //spock
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy" //avoids conflicts with groovy version
    }
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:testInProgress-client:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.imaginea.jenkins.plugins:testInProgress-spock-client:0.1'
    testCompile( 'com.athaydes:spock-reports:1.2.13' ) {
        transitive = false // this avoids affecting your version of Groovy/Spock
    }
    testCompile "io.appium:java-client:4.1.2" //needed for appium
    agent "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9" //needed for allure reports

}

allure {
    autoconfigure = true
    version = '2.8.1'
}


tasks.withType(Test) {

    maxHeapSize = "128m"
    testLogging {
        
        debug {
            events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
            exceptionFormat "full"
        }
        info.events = debug.events
        info.exceptionFormat = debug.exceptionFormat

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably worth mentioning, that I have 2 projects, that are fundamentally the same, with slight flavor differences. One runs on Android 9 and generates Allure .json reports with no problems. Then there's this problem child that I can't generate the reports on, is running on Android 4.3. Other than that, I can't seem to figure out what other differences there may be. If anyone can point out where to look, that'd be great.
I'm on Gradle v.6.5, in case that matters.
Any insight is greatly appreciated!!!